# UWP background raw push notifications

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to get raw push notifications to go to a background task.  This already works when the app is in the foreground, so I know it's not anything with getting the notification delivered.

Here's the steps I used.

In the manifest:

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="TestApp.BackgroundNotifications">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="pushNotification" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

The background class:

```
namespace TestApp {
  public sealed class BackgroundNotifications : IBackgroundTask {
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
      Debug.WriteLine("Got background notification");
    }
  }
}
```

And then the registration:

```
  BackgroundAccessStatus status =
    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
  BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder =
    new BackgroundTaskBuilder {
      Name = "MyBackgroundNotifications",
      TaskEntryPoint = "TestApp.BackgroundNotifications"
    };
  taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());
  BackgroundTaskRegistration myTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

When I send a raw push notification I see this in the log but not my debug message:

```
The program '[16660] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is right. In your steps, it seems you've forgotten to **Reference the background tasks project from your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app project.**

In your UWP app, you can right click on **References** and select **Add Reference**. Under **Projects**, select **Solution** and then select the name of your background task project and click **OK**.

After this, you can rebuild your project, then your background task should be able to work.

For more info, please see [Create and register an out-of-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task).

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I didn't understand that it had to be in its own project.